# Create NFC tag Payment with Token

Tags: nfc, payment-processing, mastercard

[Visa](https://developer.visa.com/products/vts) and Mastercard are working on a card tokenization, and I wondered if it was possible with this token stored on a NFC-tag like a key-fob to perform a contactless payment?

Do you think it is enough to put the token on the NFC-tag or is it must be wrapped ?

It will work like the [visa ring](http://pressreleases.visa.com/phoenix.zhtml?c=215693&p=irol-newsarticlePR&ID=2174656).

Comment: Related: [MIFARE card for payment with EMVco compliance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39341413/2425802)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but with a lot of conditions (nothing is simple, sorry).

The keyfob must have a real Secure Element inside that can run an applet that complies to Visa/Mastercard specifications. A simple NDEF tag would not do: this is not just about storing some data, but it is about an application handling it securely.

In other words: the 'token' has to be stored securely on the chip, and the chip shall send it only to a reader that has authenticated itself properly to the chip.
The specifications are freely available, have a look at 'EMV'.